# Создание объектов дженериков без передачи аргументов?

Tags: java, generics, syntax

Какая разница/последствия/особенности следующих способов создать объектов? (Все выполняются без ошибок):

```
public class Solution<T> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Solution object1 = new Solution(); //1
        Solution<Integer> object2 = new Solution(); //2
        Solution object3 = new Solution<Integer>(); //3

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все три неправильные. Но показать опасности на вашем примере сложно, надо его немного расширить:

```
public class Solution<T> {
    private T value;

    public Solution() { }

    public Solution(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
    }
}
```

1. Первый вариант вообще не использует обобщения и оперирует *сырым* типом. Это, во-первых, не позволит компилятору автоматически подставить приведения типов и их придётся делать вручную. А во-вторых, компилятор не может проверить соответствия типов, при операциях с объектом `object1`, и в поле `val` может оказаться например экземпляр класса [Dimension](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html), когда ваш код ожидает `Integer`. Возникнет ошибка во время выполнения.

   ```
   Solution object1 = new Solution();
   object1.setValue(new Dimension());
   int x = 42 + (Integer) object1.getValue();  // Ошибка!
   ```
2. Второй вариант присваивает переменной параметризированного типа
   ссылку на *сырой* тип. Теперь компилятор может защитить вас от такой ошибки `object2.setVal(new Dimension)`, но не от такой:

   ```
   Solution<Integer> object2 = new Solution(new Dimension());
   int x = 42 + object2.getValue();  // Ошибка!
   ```
3. Третий вариант теряет параметр типа при присваивании ссылки
   параметризированного типа переменной сырого типа. Ситуация обратная предыдущей, компилятор не даст создать объект с неправильным содержимым, но не сможет проверить типобезопасность операций с переменной:

   ```
   Solution object3 = new Solution<Integer>();
   object3.setValue(new Dimension());
   int x = 42 + (Integer) object3.getValue();  // Ошибка!
   ```